# What is the product of all nonzero, finite cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

To be specific, why does the following equality hold?
$$
\prod_{0\lt n\lt\omega}n=2^{\aleph_0}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a product of *cardinals*, yes:

$$2^{\aleph_0} \leq \prod_{0 < n < \omega} n \leq {\aleph_0}^{\aleph_0} \leq 2^{\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$$

As a product of *ordinals*, no:

$$\prod_{0 < n < \omega} n \leq \prod_{0 < n < \omega} \omega = {\omega}^{\omega}$$ 
but the ordinal ${\omega}^{\omega}$ is countable.

Comment: The ordinal product of finite numbers is simply $\omega$.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: How do you know off the bat that $2^{\aleph_0} \leq \prod_{0 < n < \omega} n $?

Comment: @pookie: This is exactly the argument given in my answer. You take a product of *smaller* cardinals over the same index set.

Comment: To clarify, does it actually hold for a product of ordinals? The answer and comments look like they conflict a little.

Comment: @pookie: It does not hold for ordinal product, since the product is countable (it is equal to $\omega$), while $2^{\aleph_0}$ is not countable. Mind that ordinal product and cardinal product are different operations.

Comment: Oh, I think I was thrown off since the answer seems to say that the ordinal product is $\omega^\omega$, not $\omega$, although I guess the conclusion would be the same.

Comment: @pookie: I was lazy and wrote it is at most $\omega^{\omega}$ (which also countable, as this is ordinal exponentiation), and this is enough to give the conclusion.

Comment: @sdcvvc: I edited in the word "ordinal" to make it absolutely clear, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

If $\displaystyle f\in\prod_{n\in\omega} 2$ then $f(n)\in\{0,1\}$, and in particular for $n>1$ we have that $f(n)\in n$. Therefore this is a proper subset of $\displaystyle f\in\prod_{0<n<\omega} n$, therefore the cardinality is *at least* continuum.

On the other hand $\omega^\omega$ has cardinality continuum, and the same argument shows that the product is a  subset of $\displaystyle\prod_{n\in\omega}\omega$

Comment: I'm reading your answer to understand the first inequality in what sdcvvc wrote, but I don't understand the bit "Therefore this is a proper subset of f" What is a proper subset of $f$, and why are we interested in proper subsets of $f$ anyway, given that $f$ is a function? (Oh, I know that every function can be viewed as a relation, and hence that a proper subset of a function is just a a restriction of the original function, but I don't see the significance *here*.)

Comment: I think that I meant to say that $\prod_{n\in\omega}2\subseteq\prod_{n\in\omega}n$.