# Cardinal of an infinite Cartesian Product of finite increasing sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $X_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$. I want to compute the cardinal of $\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n:=\{f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n: f(n)\in X_n\}$.
I believe that its cardinal is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

I have been able to show that
\begin{align}
\left|\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n\right|\geq 2^{\aleph_0}.
\end{align}

In order to show that $\left|\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n\right|\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, I am trying to find a one to one map from the set $\{f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n: f(n)\in X_n\}$ to the set $\{g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}\}$ but I am not able to find it. Is it even possible?

Any hint to find such a map?
Is it correct that $\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90191/what-is-the-product-of-all-nonzero-finite-cardinals may help.

Comment: But is there any way to show equality by obtaining a one-to-one map from one set to the other?

Comment: You mean Cantor–Bernstein?

Comment: Maybe you can repeat the proof of the "$\prod_{0 < n < \omega} n \leq {\aleph_0}^{\aleph_0} \leq 2^{\aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$" step in the link and compose those injections to obtain an injection, but that is not the answer that you want probably.

Comment: I want to use Cantor–Bernstein to finish the argument, but before I need to show that $|\prod X_n|<2^{\aleph_0}$ and to do that I would like to find a one-to-one function from $\prod X_n$ to $\{g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

$$\varphi:\prod_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}X_n\to\wp(\Bbb Z^+):f\mapsto\left\{2^n3^{f(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\,.$$

That should be good enough for your purposes, but if you really want a map to ${^{\Bbb Z^+}}\{0,1\}$, you can use $f\mapsto\chi_{\varphi(f)}$, mapping $f$ to the indicator (characteristic) function of $\varphi(f)$. The set $\varphi(f)$ is a fairly standard way of encoding the ordered pairs making up $f$ as single positive integers. (I have used $\Bbb Z^+$ here instead of $\Bbb N$, because for me the latter includes $0$.)